# Which dependencie version should I use when remapping?

Tags: solidity

When I remap dependencies for a brownie project, I have to indicate which version of the github repository should be used, e.g:

```
dependencies:
  - smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@chainlink=smartcontractkit/chainlink-brownie-contracts@1.1.1'
```

Is it usually save to use the latest version of the repo or is there any reason to chose an older version, for example to avoid importing bugs etc.?